# Knowing concentration, can we say one random variable is bounded by another?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If we have two random variables $X, Y$, such that for any $\varepsilon \in (0, 1]$ we have
$$\mathbb{P} \left( | X - Y | \geq \varepsilon \right) \leq C $$
for some constant $C > 0$, can we say that in particular $|X|$ is bounded by $Z := |Y| + 1$  with probability at least $1-C$ ?

This seems intuitive, but I can't see the formal argument here. I always find it difficult to manipulate these kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|X|>|Y|+1$ implies $|X-Y| \geq |X|-|Y|>1>\epsilon$ so $P(|X|>|Y|+1) \leq C$ or $P(|X|\leq |Y|+1) \geq 1-C$ . So the answer is YES.

Comment: That was simpler than expected, thank you!